# Listing directories with name and size

Tags: powershell, directory, size, get-childitem

I would like to list directories with Fullname, Size, LastWriteTime and recurse till the third level.

```
Get-ChildItem -Depth 3 |
    Where-Object {
        $_.PSIsContainer
        } |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.FullName + ";" + "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse |
            Measure-Object Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1MB) + " MB"+";"+ $_.LastWriteTime
        }
```

But the size gets only measured for the directories in the first level.

The output is:

```
C:\folder1\folder2 ; 487,69 MB ; 30.01.2020 17:58:45
C:\folder1\folder2\folder3 ; 0,00 MB ; 30.01.2020 17:59:34
C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4 ; 0,00 MB ; 30.01.2020 17:59:37
```

But it should be like this, since I put the same file in each folder:

```
C:\folder1\folder2 ; 1463,07 MB ; 30.01.2020 17:58:45
C:\folder1\folder2\folder3 ; 975,38 MB ; 30.01.2020 17:59:34
C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4 ; 487,69 MB ; 30.01.2020 17:59:37
```

Comment: So you are wanting to get all the directories within three subtrees of your `Get-ChildItem`, then wanting to loop through all the files inside to get a length and then report each of the 3 deep directories with their size?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It works for C:\directory1, but when it comes to the second and the third level (C:\directory1\directory2 and C:\directory1\directory2\directory3), the value of Size will be always be 0.00 MB.

Comment: @MarcJefferson5 - your _desired_ results show the same size for all subdirs. do you really have all the files in `folder4`?

Comment: You're right. I corrected it.

Comment: @MarcJefferson5 - excellent! thanks ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

This outputs the `FullName`, `Size` and the `LastWriteTime` of a directory. Note that is the `size` is empty then nothing is outputted:

```
Get-ChildItem -Depth 3 | 
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer} |
    foreach{
        $size = "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse | 
            Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1MB)

        if ($size){
            Write-Host $_.FullName  ";"  $size "MB" ";" $_.LastWriteTime
        }
    }
```

Let us know how you get on.

## Update

Following the update to your question, please try the following code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Depth 3 | 
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer} |
    foreach{
        $folders = Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse

        [int]$totalSize = 0
        
        foreach ($folder in $folders){
            $totalSize += (Get-ItemProperty -Path $folder.FullName -Name Length -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Length)
        }

        if ($totalSize){
            Write-Host $_.FullName  ";"  $totalSize ";" $_.LastWriteTime
        }
    }
```

It can probably be cleaned up, I just want to see if this works as you want it :)

Comment: It still doesn't output Size correctly for the subtrees.

Comment: `C:\folder1\folder2 ; 487,69 MB ; 30.01.2020 17:58:45
C:\folder1\folder2\folder3 ; 0,00 MB ; 30.01.2020 17:59:34
C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4 ; 0,00 MB ; 30.01.2020 17:59:37`

Comment: Can you please update your question with what you would expect to get along with what you are currently getting?

Comment: Yes, the updated code is working how I wanted it. At first look it seemed like the values were not correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is check every sub-directory's content, and add that to it's parent total. That parent then has to tell it's super-parent, and that grandparent => great grandparent, etc.

Every file has to inform every ancestor of it's size, or else the directories nested 30 deep with gigs of data will have no way to tell the C: drive how big it is, for instance.

This is a recursion problem, and you can either do it by calling the function on each child, or creating a queue and processing each child as you get to it.

You can also either calculate each directory, and then have the directories roll up their results, or you can have each file report up. Depending on if you have a wide or deep file structure, this could make a difference, but maybe negligible.

I wrote this as a queue with each file reporting up. It's a little easier to follow if you break through the code than with a calls stack and a final rollup, in my opinion.

```
function Get-DirSize {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0,
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            HelpMessage = "Directory path")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        $name = (Get-Item  ".")
        , [switch]$force
    )
    $name = Get-Item $name
    $q = New-Object System.Collections.Queue
    $results = New-Object System.Collections.Queue
    $q.Enqueue([PSCustomObject]@{
            Parent    = $null
            Directory = $name
            Size      = 0
            Depth     = 0
        })
    do {
        $dir = $q.Dequeue()
        $results.Enqueue($dir)
        $children = $dir.Directory | Get-ChildItem -Force:$force
        foreach ($child in $children) {
            if ($child.PSIsContainer ) {
                $q.Enqueue([PSCustomObject]@{
                        Parent    = $dir
                        Directory = $child
                        Size      = 0
                        Depth     = $dir.Depth + 1
                    })
            }
            else {
                $tempDir = $dir
                while ($tempDir) {
                    $tempDir.Size += $child.length
                    $tempDir = $tempDir.Parent
                }
            }
        }
    } until ($q.Count -eq 0)
    $ret = $results | ForEach-Object {
        $dir = $_
        return [PSCustomObject]@{
            FullName      = $dir.Directory.FullName
            LastWriteTime = $dir.Directory.LastWriteTime
            Size          = $dir.Size
            Depth         = $dir.Depth
            PSDirObject   = $dir.Directory
        } 
    }
    return $ret
}
```

You then call it, and you can pass a directory you want to check, or the current working directory. The -force flag is just passed along to get-childitem and will have the same effect.

```
Get-DirSize "c:\development" -force | Where-Object Depth -LE 3 | Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime, @{n = "Size"; e = { "$($_.Size / 1MB)" + "MB" } }
```

The output has to be filtered by depth, and you can pick which columns you want with a custom select statement.